# Combinatorics - throwing colored dice

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We throw 5 colored dice in the colors: blue, red, yellow, green, orange.

How many results are they for:

1) In total

2) At least one die has the number '3'

3) Exactly one die has the number '2' and exactly one die has the number '4'

4) The **set** of results contains only 3 members - what it means is that only 3 numbers will be in the results (e.g 1 1 1 2 3)

What I did is that:

1) In total there are $6^5$

2) I'll take the total number of combinations and subtract all the possible ways '3' is not picked. 
$6^5-5^5$

3) I'll choose one die to represent '2', and one to represent '4'

${4 \choose 2} \cdot 4^5$

I'm having trouble solving the last question, I'm also not sure about my solutions.

Can anyone please verify it and/or give me a suggestion for the last exercise?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural; dices means to cut into small cubes.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers for $(1)$ and $(2)$ are correct.

(3) $5\cdot4$ ways to place the $2$ specified #s and $4^3$ ways to fill the other places, so $5\cdot4\cdot4^3$

(4) *Patterns* with only $3$ numbers are:

$3-1-1-0-0-0:$
$\left[\binom61\binom52\;\text{ways to choose the numbers}\right]\times\left[\frac{5!}{3!}\text{ ways to permute them}\right]$

$2-2-1-0-0-0:$
$\left[\binom62\binom41\;\text{ways to choose the numbers}\right]\times\left[\frac{5!}{2!2!} \text{ ways to permute them}\right]$

Add up.

Comment: Oh, this way is very clear.

Comment: @Masacroso: Thank you for your kind comments.

Answer (score 2):

3) Is not right: because 2 and 4 are different numbers you have $\binom{5}{2}\cdot 2!=(5)_2=20$ ways to choose pairs of dice on 5 dice, one 2 and other 4 (this is named variations without repetitions). The others 3 dice have 4 values to take so the total will be $20\cdot4^3$.

4) My interpretation of this is that in a throw they are only 3 different values present. The different ways to have only 3 values are these groups ABCCC and ABBCC.

1. The combinations of groups of A, B and C members are $\binom{A+B+C}{A,B,C}$, this is the multinomial coefficient. For the first case is $\frac{5!}{3!}=20$, and for the second is $\frac{5!}{4}=30$. But for every ABC combination there are 2 indistinguishable groups, i.e., two groups of the same cardinality, so the total amount of distinguishable combinations when values would be placed are $(30+20)\frac12=25$.
2. The ordered combinations of 3 different values over 6 possible are $(6)_3=120$. We need ordered combinations (=variations) instead of just combinations because we are putting the 3 different values on the groups A, B and C in any different order.

Then the answer for the four question is $25\cdot 120=3000$ distinguishable throws with 3 different values.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for 1) and 2) are correct.

3) You have 5 choices for the dice that will show '2', then 4 choices for the one that will show '4'. Others cannot be '2' or '4'. So there are $5.4.4^3$ possibilities

Question 4) is not clear

Comment: 2) Is not right... you are counting many combinations repeated. The easy way is to solve in negative: total ways less the possibilities for no one 3, as the OP did.

Comment: Yes, sorry and thanks. Edited.